# Payment processing on the web in general -  A compendium

Tags: web-services, web-applications, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I was looking for payment related topic and I noticed that there is no 'general' discussion about that.   I intend to build shop  on the web and I am looking for compendium about techniques which can be used for that purpose. I wish to use VISA, Master, PayPal, etc.

Please outline your methods. There are no limitations like programming language, gateway provider, library, CMS, or whatever. I am looking for ways to implement payments. I do not know if it is better to implement it from scratch or use a CMS, with ready to use modules. If you will describe your point of view on this topic I would appreciate that. State the pros and cons of you method. Please help me and provide an overview on this topic.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Paypal](http://paypal.com)

Paypal fairly easy to implements with its extensive (but messy) documentation. It accepts all mayor credit cards (Visa, Master, Discover, AmEx) and is used by a large part of the internet oriented (international) population.

Also, **[this is an interesting read by Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/11/taking-credit-card-payments-online-whats-involved/)** about payments processing.